# Sql Server 2005 refuses to install on Windows 2008 R2 -- cannot find sql.cab

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, windows-server-2008-r2

I  am installing SQL Server 2005 Standard for a customer on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine at Hostgator.  Both Windows and SQL Server are 64-bit editions.

My customer has copied all her disks up to a folder on the server.  I go through the process and am told that an installer package could not be found on the installation media.  If I specifically run SqlRun.msi, the message specifies that it cannot find sql.cab.

Suspecting a corrupt copy, I got her to copy the folder again.  the same thing happened.  She pointed out that she'd copied the Disk 1 and Disk 2 options as well as the all-in-one disk.  So I tried from Disk 1.  The same thing happened.

At this point corrupt media and corrupt copying do not seem like reasonable answers as she's copied 2x from one of the media and has copied 2 different media sets -- and the exact same thing has happened.

Here's the end of the verbose Windows Installer log:
=== Logging stopped: 6/19/2014  8:14:12 ===
MSI (c) (18:EC) [08:14:12:498]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (c) (18:EC) [08:14:12:498]: Product: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 (64-bit) -- Installation failed.

MSI (c) (18:EC) [08:14:12:498]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 (64-bit). Product Version: 9.00.1399.06. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1603.

MSI (c) (18:EC) [08:14:12:514]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (18:EC) [08:14:12:514]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (c) (18:EC) [08:14:12:530]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 6/19/2014  8:14:12 ===

I tried the hotfix at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950636 but it refused to run, saying it was not applicable to the OS.

I tried turning off the firewall per http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/a9dc9b5a-6cf4-490d-bfbd-909818e45db0/cant-install-ss-2005-cant-find-sqlcab and that didn't help.  It didn't seem to make sense, but I'll try almost anything.

Windows Installer is already at version 5, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

What else would you suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: I've had similar installation issues like this before. In those cases, it was related to corrupt source files. 
Maybe download a fresh trial edition and see if that installs ok?

Comment: Trial editions of SQL 2005 are no longer available from MS.  Why not upgrade?  b/c the user has spent $5000 on this edition and is in no mood to repeat that purchase!

Comment: My customer uploaded from 2 different media sources, the DVD and the pair of CD's.  Both resulted in the same error.  So I really don't think bad media are the problem.

Comment: In my case, the source was the issue. In your case, I don't know what the issue is. Maybe install (test install) into a VM with fresh OS, confirm its OK, go from there. Just an idea... but... I do understand your situation could be quite different.